# Is there a module over a noncommutative domain in which the torsion elements do not form a submodule?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, noncommutative-algebra

In my advanced Algebra course, we were told to prove when $R$ is an integral domain and $M$ an $R$-module, $\textrm{Tor}(M)$ is a submodule of $M$ (here $\textrm{Tor}(M)$ denotes the *torsion* of $M$, which is the elements of $M$ that vanish somewhere on some nonzero element of $R$).  As a supplementary exercise, we were told to find a simple example of a ring $R$ and module $M$ where $\textrm{Tor}(M)$ was *not* an $R$-submodule of $M$, and clearly $R$ couldn't be an integral domain by the previous result.

Now finding an example is simple enough.  Personally I used the example $R=M=\mathbb{Z}/6$ and I got an A on the test overall.  But I'm wondering, is there an example where $R$ is not an integral domain, but instead of removing the no-zero-divisors property, we instead remove commutativity?  I'm thinking it would have to be either a subring of -or constructed from- quaternions, but I'm not very familiar with this.

---

Note: While $R$ an integral domain is a sufficient condition for $\textrm{Tor}(M)$ to be a submodule, it is not necessary, as $R=M=\mathbb{Z}/4$ has torsion $\{0,2\}$, which is a submodule.

Comment: For noncommutative domains that satisfy the right Ore conditions, the proof still holds. That’s why you need one that isn’t right Ore :). (As give by Eric)

Comment: I had never heard of that condition, but thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: It's good to know, basic topic for noncommutative algebra courses. Ore domains are the tamest of noncommutative domains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $R$ be the free ring on two elements $x$ and $y$.  Explicitly, $R=\mathbb{Z}\langle x,y\rangle$ is the ring of noncommutative polynomials in $x$ and $y$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$.  You can easily check that this is a (noncommutative) domain by looking only at top-degree terms.

Now let $I\subset R$ be the left ideal generated by $x$ and let $M=R/I$.  Explicitly, $I$ consists of polynomials in which all the monomials end in $x$, so $M$ can by identified with the set of polynomials which contain no monomials that end in $x$, with the action of $R$ on $M$ defined as usual except that $x\cdot 1=0$.  So, $1\in\operatorname{Tor}(M)$, but $y\not\in\operatorname{Tor}(M)$.  Since $y=y\cdot 1$, this means $\operatorname{Tor}(M)$ is not a submodule of $M$.

Comment: Just to test my understanding, how is it we can say "...defined as usual except that $x\cdot 1=0$...".  Can we arbitrarily invoke this property and still have a module action?

Comment: Well, that was a somewhat informal description.  More formally, since $R$ is free on $x$ and $y$, an $R$-module action on an abelian group is uniquely determined by specifying two endomorphisms to be the actions of $x$ and $y$.  So, I'm saying the action of $y$ is as usual, and the action of $x$ is as usual on all the monomials except for $1$, with $x\cdot 1=x$.

Comment: I think you meant $x\cdot 1=0$, but I get what you mean.  If I recall correctly, that's due to the universal property of free modules?

Comment: Oops, yes, that's what I meant.  Here I'm using the universal property of the free _ring_ $R$.  (And, I suppose, also the universal property of $M$ as a free abelian group on its monomials, to specify the action of $x$ and $y$ only on the monomials.)